# Counts of occurrences for column combinations

Tags: r, matrix

I have a dataset with three variables (X1,X2,X3) and these variables only take the value of 0 or 1.

The dataset is

```
dput(data)
structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), .Dim = c(10L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("x1", "x2", "x3")))
```

In the example above each row is an observation and each column is a variable.

I need to know the frequency of

(X1=1), (X2=1), (X3=1), (X1=1,X2=1), (X1=1,X3=1), (X2=1,X3=1), (X1=1,X2=1,X3=1)

I tried

```
table(rowSums(data !=0))
```

But this only give me the frequencies of one, two or three variables happens.

Comment: How about `library(reshape2);table(melt(data)[-1])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
comb <- sapply(1:3, combn, x = 3)
find <- function(colComb) sum(rowSums(data.frame(df[, colComb])) == length(colComb))
list <- sapply(comb, function(colComb) apply(colComb, 2, find))
names(list) <- sapply(comb, function(colComb) paste(apply(colComb, 2, paste, collapse = "&"), collapse = "|"))

$`1|2|3`
[1] 10  9  4

$`1&2|1&3|2&3`
[1] 9 4 3

$`1&2&3`
[1] 3
```

As suggested by user2957945 the short version:

```
lapply(1:3, function(x) combn(3, x, FUN=function(y) sum(Reduce("&", as.data.frame(df[,y])))))
```

Comment: in my version of data.table it would have to be : `dat[,..y]` otherwise it throws me an error and i am not sure  which question it answers since `mean` should be `sum/N` no?

Comment: Im not using data.table. Not quite sure what you mean, sorry, I suggested mean as the Q asked for frequency (as opposed to count). If you change sum to mean you get sum / N as expected (which id think of more of a frequency)

Comment: ah, as you see above my dataframe was called df not dat, but i had a data.table `dat ` in my namespace, that caused confusion ;) Nice solution! You wanna create another answer or should i make an edit?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `xtabs` which is meant for three-way tables:

```
s <- structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), .Dim = c(10L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
NULL, c("x1", "x2", "x3")))

mytab <- xtabs(~x1+x2+x3, data = s)

mytab

, , x3 = 0

   x2
x1  0 1
  1 0 6

, , x3 = 1

   x2
x1  0 1
  1 1 3
```

If you would like it to look better, follow this up with `ftable`

```
ftable(mytab)

      x3 0 1
x1 x2       
 1  0     0 1
    1     6 3
```

Please note though, your example only has one value for `x1`.